# Python how to include os.path.abs to pyodbc connection string

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access, ms-access-2007, connection-string, pyodbc

Still pretty new to python , Im trying to include os.path.abs to my connection string.

```
 con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ='+os.path.abspath.join+'mydb.mdb;')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

abspath is a function that needs to be called

Try this:

```
con = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ='+os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), 'mydb.mdb') +';')
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch